# i click in a button and change the value of input but i dont have any answer of server with react testing library

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I tried userEvent of testinglibrary and fireEvent but i dont have any success...

```
it('Deve renderizar o processo lista', async () => {
const { getByText, getByRole } = render(
  <HelmetProvider>
    <MemoryRouter>
      <ProcessoGerenciamento />
    </MemoryRouter>
  </HelmetProvider>,
);
act(() => {
  const botaofiltrar = getByRole('button', { name: /filtrar/i });
  fireEvent.input(getByRole('textbox', { name: /número do processo/i }), { target: { value: '1' } });
  fireEvent.click(botaofiltrar);
});
await waitFor(() => {
  const processo = getByText('Processos');
  expect(processo).toBeInTheDocument();
});});
```

and the class related of have 3 components

```
 <div>
    <ProcessoFiltro
      retornoFiltro={filtrarProcesso}
      tiposProcesso={listaTiposProcesso}
      situacoes={listaSituacao}
      loadingButton={carregando}
      resetFiltro={resetFiltroFormData}
    />
    {Object.keys(filtroFormData).length > 0 && <div className="br-divider"></div>}
    {Object.keys(filtroFormData).length > 0 && (
      <ProcessoLista
        filtro={filtroFormData}
        loading={carregando}
        sort={filtroOrdenacao}
        cabecalhoTabela={camposTabela}
      />
    )}
    {Object.keys(filtroFormData).length > 0 && (
      <Paginacao retornoPaginacao={filtroPaginacao} metaDataPaginacao={metadata} />
    )}
  </div>
```

i click a button in the first component and i have a server request, then i recieve a object and setFiltroFormData but in the test doesnt work

SORRY MY BAD ENGLISH.